# Multiple property listeners wait for both to trigger callback

Tags: matlab, properties, callback, listeners

I am having a little trouble in Matlab regarding property listeners. I have added a listener to the `XLim` and `YLim` properties of an axis, triggered on `PostSet`:

```
h = addlistener(myaxes,{'XLim','YLim'},'PostSet',@myfunc);
```

Now I want my program to do something after both properties have changed, or if only one has changed, but in the latter case I must be sure that the other one was not changed.

When using the zoom tool on the axes, the properties always change both and always in the order `x`, then `y`. So in this case I would not have a problem, but sometimes I am setting the `XLim` or `YLim` properties programmatically and want the same function to trigger. Somehow I must be able to tell if only one of these two properties has triggered the listener or both.

In the current stage, my callback executes twice: once for `XLim` and once for `YLim`. I want it to execute exactly once, and exactly after I know there is no further change to the two properties. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it can be possible to detect the "simultaneous" `set` directly, because the actual property assignments, not just the `PostSet` events, are executed separately, and no additional information is passed to the `PostSet` callback that lets you know another one is coming. Stopped on a breakpoint in the first callback, the axes fully update to their new `XLim` without any sign of the coming change to `YLim`.

There are quite a number of ways to put together a workaround depending on what you can assume about the way the code will be used and what your priorities are. All the ones I can think of use at least one of the following principles:

- Use a timer at some stage to allow for a possible `YLim` assignment to trigger a second callback before completing the work of an `XLim` `PostSet` callback
- Create a custom routine for assignment of `XLim` without `YLim` to differentiate in some way from assignments made by things like the zoom tool
- Make use of the fact that the zoom tool sets the `XLimMode` property first, whether or not there is a change to its value. Setting `XLim` programmatically will not set `XLimMode` if its value is already `manual`.